# Why is the array in my redux reducer not available from another component after a redirect to another page of my app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have two separate components. I want to have a `button` that when clicked on will add an `element` to an array in my `reducer` and `redirect` to another `component`, this `component` that gets redirected to needs to render the data that was just added to the `array`. The page redirects to the `component` I want but the data does not load and the `console.logs` don't show anything.

This is the `component` that has the redirect button. On this `component` the `console.log(socialNetworkContract.members[0])` shows the string I expect.

```
const Posts = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const getProfile = async (member) => {
        const addr = await dispatch({ type: 'ADD_MEMBER', response: member })
        console.log(member)
        window.location.href='/member'
        console.log('----------- member------------')
        console.log(socialNetworkContract.members[0])
    }
    const socialNetworkContract = useSelector((state) => state.socialNetworkContract)
    return (
        <div>
            {socialNetworkContract.posts.map((p, index) => {
                return <tr key={index}>
                    <button onClick={() => getProfile(p.publisher)}>Profile</button>
                </tr>})}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Posts;
```

**This is my reducer**

```
import { connect, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
let init = {
    posts:[],
    post:{},
    profiles:[],
    profile:{},
    members:[],
    member:{}
}
export const socialNetworkContract = (state = init, action) => {
    const { type, response } = action;
    switch (type) {
        case 'ADD_POST':
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: [...state.posts, response]
            }
        case 'SET_POST':
            return {
                ...state,
                post: response
            }
        case 'ADD_PROFILE':
            return {
                ...state,
                profiles: [...state.profiles, response]
            }
        case 'SET_PROFILE':
            return {
                ...state,
                profile: response
            }
        case 'ADD_MEMBER':
            return {
                ...state,
                members: [...state.members, response]
            }
        case 'SET_MEMBER':
            return {
                ...state,
                member: response
            }

        default: return state
    }
};
```

and this is the component that is redirected to. this just says undefined in `console.log(socialNetworkContract.members[0])`

```
const Member = () => {  
const [user, setUser] = useState({});
const socialNetworkContract = useSelector((state) => state.socialNetworkContract)

useEffect(async()=>{
    try {
        const pro = socialNetworkContract.members[0]
        console.log(socialNetworkContract.members[0])
        await setUser(pro)
        console.log(socialNetworkContract.members[0])

    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
}, [])
```

I have the route set in `Routes.js` as

```
<Route path="/member" exact component={Member} />
```

Comment: Because you redirected--the page you were on with its JS/data/etc is gone. If you want an SPA you have to write one, if you don't then you need a persistent store.

Comment: use `react-router-dom` when you use `window.location.href` it reloads your whole page. If you want the data on your second route you have to be on SPA mod.

Comment: I would suggest looking into connected-react-router (a redux store plugin for react-router) and then you can just use `dispatch(push("/member"));` https://www.npmjs.com/package/connected-react-router

Answer (score 1):

Use `history.push('/')` instead of `window.location.href` which will `reload` your whole page and you will lost your local state data.

```
const {withRouter} from "react-router-dom";

const Posts = (props) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const getProfile = async (member) => {
        const addr = await dispatch({ type: 'ADD_MEMBER', response: member })
        console.log(member)
        props.history.push('/member');
        console.log('----------- member------------')
        console.log(socialNetworkContract.members[0])
    }

    const socialNetworkContract = useSelector((state) => state.socialNetworkContract)
    return (
        <div>
            {socialNetworkContract.posts.map((p, index) => {
                return <tr key={index}>
                    <button onClick={() => getProfile(p.publisher)}>Profile</button>
                </tr>})}
        </div>
    )
}

export default withRouter( Posts );
```

Comment: I get 'props' is not defined  no-undef when I do that. I am writting with hooks

Comment: you need to get the props from params. Also if you gonna use above `snippet` wrap your component to `withRouter` because without that you will not get `push` function.